# URL Rewrite for calendar site

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to make the URL for my calendar site look nicer with .htaccess, but I can't get it to work.

---

I already have a rule, that removes the .php extension, and it works perfect. It looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
# turn on the mod_rewrite engine

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
# IF the request filename with .php extension is a file which exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
# AND the request is not for a directory
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
# redirect to the php script with the requested filename
```

My current URL look like this:
http://mydomain.com/calendar/calendar-site?year=2013&month=november

... and I want to make it look like this:
http://mydomain.com/calendar/2013/November

The site works perfect without the rewrite, where I use $_GET[] to get the values for year and month in the URL, but with the rewrite on, it cannot get the values from the url.

---

I have tried these *(not both at once of course)*:

```
RewriteRule ^calendar/([^/]*)$ /calendar-site.php?year=$1&month=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /calendar-site.php?year=$1&month=$2 [L]
```

The first one creates a 404 page and the second one cannot get the values from the url + it mess up the stylesheet.

---

Hope you guys can help me out here :D

Thanks - Jesper

Comment: Forgot to say, that the .htaccess file, is located in the "calender"-folder, and not in the root of my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, but in your first try you only included one matching group for the year and not one for the month. Include the character class twice to match the year which is captured to `$1` and again for the month captured in `$2`. Use `RewriteBase` to set the root for your redirect. Note that the "month" value will be in the same case as in the URL.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^calendar/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /calendar/calendar-site.php?year=$1&month=$2 [L]
```

Test using http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

```
input url
http://mydomain.com/calendar/2013/november

output url
http://mydomain.com/calendar/calendar-site.php

debugging info
1 RewriteBase /
2 RewriteRule ^calendar/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /calendar/calendar-site.php?year=$1&month=$2 [L]
  This rule was met, the new url is http://mydomain.com/calendar/calendar-site.php
  The tests are stopped because the L in your RewriteRule options
```

Comment: Thanks mate :) The RewriteBase solved my problem.
This is my code:
RewriteBase /kalender/
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /kalender/calendar-test?year=$1&month=$2 [L]

But the css file is not loaded. It seems that the site think that it is located in http://mydomain.com/calendar/2013/css/style.css which is not right. Any idea how to solve that? :D

Comment: It seems like it doesn't know that the css is an actual file